# How to select the combination of samples that sum of combination follows a specific distribution?

Tags: r, sum, combinations, distribution

I have two 30 samples datasets.

```
A1 <- c(368.4777, 387.9693, 403.7576, 417.4397, 429.7728, 441.1835, 451.9409, 462.2286, 472.1809, 481.9012, 491.4738, 500.9705, 510.4558, 519.9902, 529.6330, 539.4454, 549.4926, 559.8473, 570.5931, 581.8296, 593.6794, 606.2988, 619.8938, 634.7472, 651.2666, 670.0744, 692.1994, 719.5452, 756.3235, 815.7298)

B1 <- c(414.2523,  471.8087,  519.1119,  560.4502,  597.9043,  632.6668,  665.5000,  696.9308,  727.3477,  757.0533,  786.2953,  815.2867,  844.2194,  873.2745,  902.6306,  932.4719,  962.9959,  994.4228, 1027.0068, 1061.0519, 1096.9331, 1135.1297, 1176.2765, 1221.2488, 1271.3134, 1328.4178, 1395.8053, 1479.5340, 1593.1899, 1780.2717)
```

If I want to sum two distributions,

1. `A1+B1`will give me a green dotted line density plot.
2. `rowSums(expand.grid(A1, B1))` will give me blue solid line density plot. (30*30=900 of all possible combinations)

However, I would like to make the distribution of sum similar to the red line (`Target`). In other words, I want to pick combinations from `A1` and `B1` to make the sum of combination follow red line density distribution (each value can be picked only once). How can I do this?

```
Target <- c(1691.60, 1041.01, 1581.92, 1392.43, 1806.88, 1788.24, 1838.67, 1953.35, 1253.21, 1791.36, 1644.61, 1425.05, 1218.66, 1596.36, 1305.67, 1031.98,  828.52, 1375.77, 1475.28, 1718.25)
```

[image]

Comment: how come green distribution is a lot wider than blue?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux because it is calculated like (max value of A1 + max value of B1) and (min value of A1 + min value of B1).

Comment: Same values (max+max and min+min) shall be present in `expand.grid`, isn't it? Why blue line is plotted like they're not here?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Yes you are right. that is because those are density plots that use different bandwidth. If I use the same `bw`, the density plots will be like [this](http://imgur.com/a/rH99q).

Comment: ok, got it! What I don't get is last part of your question. It might be ill-posed problem. For example, for some bins it cannot be done (1 event with sum X so you cannot remove it, or cannot add something app to red curve because your quanta is too large)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow the final part of your question, so the answer may need tweaked.

If you want to sample combinations of `A1` and `B1`, then you can just use the sample function. So

```
s1 = sample(A1) + sample(B1)
plot(density(s1))
```

This is sampling without replacement. If you want replacement, then just add `replace=TRUE` in the `sample` function.

Comment: @csfillespie Thank you for your editing and answer! My intuition is that the density distribution of 's1' is closer to the blue line, not the red line. How can we make the 's1' similar to the red line??

Comment: Yes. I tried it. Basically,  your method shows different results when I try due to it is a random sample. But it is still more like blue line, not red. <[link](http://imgur.com/Q6uRg67)> your method is a purple line.